# Trying to Get Value For in a multi level model/property association

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this extension method:

```
public static string GetValueFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    string propertyName = body.Member.Name;
    TModel model = helper.ViewData.Model;
    string value = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(model, null).ToString();
    return value;
}
```

It works very well for "one level" like this:

proj => proj.MyProperty

**So it return a value for the MyProperty located under the model.**

But it doesn't work for "multi level" like this:

proj => proj.Level1.MyProperty

**Here, trying to return a value for the MyProperty located under the model but we loose level1!**

I don't know if i'm clear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393.aspx) method and inspect result's `Model` property

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model
```